# How to get the most common combination within multiple binary columns

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

Here is a matrix 100*54, with 100 records and 53 binary variables and a dependent variable - Y/N

Part of the independent data as follows:

[image]

I managed to find the most common variable when `dependent == Y`

```
aa <- NULL
for (i in 1 : ncol(data1)) {
  aa[i] <- length(which(data1[which(data1$Output == 'Y'), i] !=0))
}
```

Now, I would like to find the most common combinations of variables that make `dependent == Y`, the numbers of the elements in the combination are not to matter.

for example, when `dependent == Y`,

```
      Combination              Count
      V1 = 1 & V2 = 1           30
      V1 = 1 & V2 = 1 & V3= 1   25
      V4 = 1 & V5 = 1           24
      ...
```

Comment: The apriori algorithm could be interesting for you: https://medium.com/@dimuthcse/apriori-algorithm-for-frequent-pattern-mining-7e8fb20b6aff In R you use the arules package to implement the algorithm

Comment: not sure about the speed but you can run `dplyr::count()`. e.g. `df %>% filter(dependent == 1) %>%  group_by_at(2:54) %>%  count() %>% arrange(-n)`

Answer (score 0):

We can *paste* all the columns then get counts:

```
# example data
set.seed(1); m1 <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 1000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4)

# all freqs
sort(table(apply(m1, 1, paste, collapse = "")))
# 1100 1111 1101 1001 0100 0101 0000 0001 0010 0011 0110 1110 0111 1011 1000 1010 
#    8    8   12   13   14   14   16   16   16   16   16   16   18   18   22   27
```

If we assume 1st col is our Yes/No column:

```
# 0 = No freqs
sort(table(apply(m1[ m1[,1] == 0, -1], 1, paste, collapse = "")))
# 100 101 000 001 010 011 110 111 
#  14  14  16  16  16  16  16  18

# 1 = Yes freqs
sort(table(apply(m1[ m1[,1] == 1, -1], 1, paste, collapse = "")))
# 100 111 101 001 110 011 000 010 
#   8   8  12  13  16  18  22  27
```